# Issue with table form html formating

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why the input boxes and the ":" aren't going left..I have changed all properties to left and looked over the padding and spacing but still nothing...any ideas? I have made a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/C7u9P/

PS: Additional question if you can answer, why is tables a bad way to make forms? A lot of the forms I have seen are tables and even menus!

Comment: GAH! Tables for layout! TABLES FOR LAYOUT!! My Eyes!!!!. And now to elaborate a bit, tables should be used for.... tabular data, which means data which is **semantically** and **logically** correct to display in tables, know what? I'll just post an answer explaining it all

Comment: Tables for forms aren't evil, but there's a better way: labels and CSS. Check out http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/examples/exampleitem/tableless_forms/

Comment: why are you using <td>Request Type:</td> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colons are aligned to the left - at least, they are aligned to the left side of their cells (td). however, the first column is very wide, and they are on a column of their own (for some reason), which makes them seem as if they're aligned to the right.

Regarding building your forms with tables, here is some discussion about it: [tables for forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395514/is-it-acceptable-to-use-tables-for-forms-or-is-it-still-more-correct-to-use-divs)

Answer (score 1):

## Why is tables for layout wrong?

### What should be used in a table?

Well, tables should only be used for what you can call **tabular data**, which means data which is presentable in a table, for example: Several payment plans and their advantages over one another, or the minimum requirements for games in different systems.

### What shouldn't be used in a table?

Practically, anything else. Especially page layout. why?

1. It causes unexpected results and cross-browser inconsistency.
2. It bloats the file size for nothing.
3. Google up "Why shouldn't I use table for layout?" to find thousands of articles on the subject.

I'm not saying tables for **form** layout is evil, but it still shouldn't be used where there is a much better (semantic) solution.

## A Better Solution

In your case, I'd use a simple form, with `<ul>` and labels, as your form is a list of items: **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/W8H7T/1/)**.

It's much more easily stylable and maintainable.

Comment: No problem, if you find my answer useful consider upvoting/accepting it, it will help me a lot :) Thanks.