# Can't get inline-block span to flow after previous span

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a span that indicates whether a field is mandatory to always flow after its text span.

I am constrained by the framework I am using in that the td and the label have the same fixed width, so this extra content must reside inside the label tag. For good measure there is a placeholder for optional content (a question/help icon) before the text item.

This is all confounded by the fact that some label texts are too long for the constrained size, so will wrap.

This is where I'm at, the asterisk should never flow underneath the text. (which is does now)

Something like:

[image]

[This is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bPGWY/)

Comment: Having dashes in class names causes weird javascript problems. I recommend renaming your classes.

Comment: source, example? never heard or encountered it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

hacked it: http://jsfiddle.net/bPGWY/12/

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `:after` CSS psuedo-selector to achieve this.

Working solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/mFrCT/

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, if cross-browser compatibility is an issue, a workaround could be http://jsfiddle.net/6BJVt/ using `position: absolute` for the required asterisk.

Comment: If cross browser compatibility is an issue, IE7 doesn't support :after (http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Aafter)

Comment: Potential solution posted for cross-browser issue. :)

Answer (score -1):

If there really is no way to get rid of those awful tables, I would suggest the following CSS:

```
td {
    position:relative;   
}
.field-mandatory {
    position:absolute;
    top:2px;
    right: 3px;   
}
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/bPGWY/11/

Comment: is a form not tabular? also i'm not keen on the big space youve left between the asterix and the label

Comment: Not realy. "Your Contents Are Tabular Data If:

If what you're going to place on the page is information that would make sense to record or track in a spreadsheet, it is almost certainly tabular data." (http://webdesign.about.com/od/tables/a/aa122605.htm)

Comment: I absolutely positioned it to the top right of that td. I understood you wanted the asterix to 'float' tot the top of the cell.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395514/is-it-acceptable-to-use-tables-for-forms-or-is-it-still-more-correct-to-use-div I'm the architect, I get to choose.

Comment: Whatever you say mister architect. But using tables for non-tabular data is just completely backwards. You're making it harder on yourself then it has to be.

Comment: it is tabular data I've established that. Anyway, the framework emits this stuff, maybe you wish to go and get pedantic over @ the Ext JS forums. No one actually cares, just jobsworths. Especially not users.