# Is it appropriate to use a table for styling a form and aligning two columns left and right

Tags: html

my question may sounds kind of stupid but I thought a lot about it. I've learned not to put forms into tables for several reasons like: 
- responsive design issues 
- even Bootstrap suggests to use divs 
- use tables for real "table-things" 
- don't design with tables

In my case I want to use a table because I want to make the form better to read and to use. I want to put labels in a left column and the input fields in a right column and align the left column right and the right column left so the labels are in the same line and close to each other. I explicit don't want to have them underneath the other because its harder to read. **With my solution the table-columns would automatically take the space they need. With twitter bootstrap for example I need to use classes like "col-xs-6" to say how width a column should be. Further sometimes all labels are kind of short so I don't need as much columns, sometimes some of them are very long so I need a lot more columns. But in my case I don't want do define this. It should happen automatically.

So my question is: Is it okay to use tables in forms in order to be okay with web standards and the state of the art? For me aligning  (left column right, right column left) is very important and not to use JavaScript. And if no is there an alternative?

[EDIT]
I've put a graphic in here which explains my problem pretty foot. I have to say: I'm looking for a solution without javascript

https://i.stack.imgur.com/75Ehm.png

Comment: No - It is not tabular data

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395514/is-it-acceptable-to-use-tables-for-forms-or-is-it-still-more-correct-to-use-div

Comment: do you have a solution without tables which follows this track? http://i.stack.imgur.com/75Ehm.png

Answer (score 0):

This code passes validation on W3C validator so designing form with tables is ok with web standarts but it s not good UI practice.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>For in the table</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
        <table>
            <caption>Form in the table</caption>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="input1">Input1</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="input1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="Submit" value="OK"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

You can use div or other containers and css something like that

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Froms with divs</title>
<style type="text/css">
form {
    margin: 0 0;
    padding: 0 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 300px;
}
input, textarea {
    width: 50%;
}
label {
    vertical-align: top;
    width:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="some-action">
        <label for="longInput">Long Input Label<input type="text" id="longInput"></label>
        <label for="inputLabel">Input Label<input type="text" id="inputLabel"></label>
        <label for="inputLabel">Short<textarea rows="" cols="" id="short"></textarea></label>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Will look like on the screenshot:
 [image]

Comment: I agee. But could you help me to find a way with good ui practice. I put a image link in my original post. My you can have a look

Comment: Added possible solution to my answer

Comment: the problem in your solution is, that you define a width for the inputs. I don't want to define this. I want it to dynamically change.

Answer (score 0):

Float `<div>`s (with CSS e.g. `float: left`) to create your form layout. Also nest your form inside a `<fieldset>`.

Comment: Is something like this possible without javascript? http://i.stack.imgur.com/75Ehm.png

Comment: Try your second solution. You could try applying CSS `min-width` to align the label column. The column should resize for longer text but stay inline for the shorter labels.