# How can I align input fields in css?

Tags: html, css

Here is the image of how I should have my form look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/77sGh.jpg
I got everything done, except I can't get the * to show in red after some lines, and also how can I align the input fields and the input names in the center horizontally?

Comment: I believe it is a simple table, first column has set (css) `text-align:right;`, while second one has `text-align:left;`. I can not help you any further without any code.... PS: I can not believe you got 3 upvotes without code.

Comment: the reason why i didnt want to upload my code was because this is an assignment, and i dont want any one from my program to find this on google and copy it lol, but basically i need to put the input and the input names in a table right?

Comment: @kecer Never use tables for layout.

Comment: @Rob: even when creating.... a table? [Personal prefference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395514/is-it-acceptable-to-use-tables-for-forms-or-is-it-still-more-correct-to-use-div)

Comment: @kecer It's not a table. It's an input form. Note that your link is from six years ago. It's not a question of personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a table as was mentioned or you could do something like this:

```
            <div>
                <!-- container for one row, ie the 'First Name' label and its text input box -->
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- the label (ie 'First Name') has its own div and the Name text box has its own div. Doing this makes it possible to left align the labels properly and align the text boxes properly -->
                    <div class="left-side"><p>First Name:</p></div>
                    <div class="right-side"><p><input type="text" class="textbox"/></p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="left-side"><p>Last Name:<p></div>
                    <div class="right-side"><p><input type="email"  class="textbox"/></p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="left-side"><p>Student ID:<p></div>
                    <div class="right-side"><p><input type="text"  class="textbox"/></p></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and so on for the whole form.

Then in your css set the `left-side` class with some width and

```
text-align: right;
```

and for the `right-side` class set some width and

```
text-align:left;
```

For the red * after each text box try putting this code after each text input box:

```
<span class="redStar">*<span>
```

and add the following css class:

```
.redStar {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: @Rob I'd like to see your answer.

Comment: @user2154149 I submitted this to be closed so I won't.